# Why is the function destroy() provided in C++20's coroutine_handle?

Tags: c++, api, c++-coroutine

Excerpted from [n4680](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4680.pdf):

> The coroutine state is destroyed when control flows off the end of the
>   coroutine or the destroy member function (18.11.2.4) of an object of
>   type std::experimental::coroutine_handle<P> associated with this
>   coroutine is invoked. In the latter case objects with automatic
>   storage duration that are in scope at the suspend point are destroyed
>   in the reverse order of the construction. The storage for the
>   coroutine state is released by calling a non-array deallocation
>   function (3.7.4.2). If destroy is called for a coroutine that is not
>   suspended, the program has undefined behavior.

**My question is:**

Now that the coroutine state will be destroyed automatically when the execution flows off the coroutine, why is an explicit function `destroy()` provided in `coroutine_handle`?

Comment: Maybe you don't want the coroutine to continue, you want to cancel its execution early?

Comment: In such a case, you can just `co_return something;`, and the coroutine context will be destroyed automatically. It seems no need to explicitly call `destroy()`.

Comment: `co_return` is to be used from "inside" the coroutine, `destroy` is to be used from the "outside". If you have a suspended coroutine, what is easier: Just call `destroy`, or set a flag and resume the coroutine and hope it will check the flag anytime soon so it can do `co_return`? There might be use-cases where you want to end the coroutine *immediately* and not let it resume to end on its own.

Comment: What @Someprogrammerdude said. In other words, it's there so that resumable objects can use it to free the memory associated with the coroutine handle when they go out of scope before co_return is executed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it necessary to call destroy on a std::coroutine\_handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68352718/is-it-necessary-to-call-destroy-on-a-stdcoroutine-handle)