# Is it necessary to call destroy on a std::coroutine_handle?

Tags: c++, c++20, coroutine

The `std::coroutine_handle` is an important part of the new coroutines of C++20. Generators for example often (always?) use it. The handle is manually destroyed in the destructor of the coroutine in all examples that I have seen:

```
struct Generator {
    // Other stuff...
    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> ch;

    ~Generator() {
        if (ch) ch.destroy();
    }
}
```

Is this really necessary? If yes, why isn't this already done by the `coroutine_handle`, is there a RAII version of the `coroutine_handle` that behaves that way, and what would happen if we would omit the `destroy` call?

Examples:

1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle (Thanks  [463035818_is_not_a_number](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/463035818-is-not-a-number))
2. The C++20 standard also mentions it in 9.5.4.10 Example 2 (checked on N4892).
3. (German) https://www.heise.de/developer/artikel/Ein-unendlicher-Datenstrom-dank-Coroutinen-in-C-20-5991142.html
4. [https://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/blog/c++-coroutines.html](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/%7Edm/blog/c++-coroutines.html) - Mentiones that it would leak if it weren't called, but does not cite a passage from the standard or why it isn't called in the destructor of `std::coroutine_handle`.

Comment: Well, it was never manually destroyed in the destructor of any coroutine in all examples I have seen...

Comment: @Fureeish Begs the question which examples were better.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Actually even the C++20 standard (I looked at n4892, but I guess the real release has a similar wording) includes it. See 9.5.4.10.

Comment: i found a am example here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle. Nevertheless I think you should include a reference to an example in your question, so others know waht you are talking about

Comment: Based on my experiences with CPPwinrt... it depends. If you're using a generator, you need to call destroy. If you're not then no.  But I wouldn't take that as authoritative. Edit [cppcoro](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro) has some examples of when it's appropriate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because you want to be able to have a coroutine outlive its handle, a handle should be **non-owning**. A handle is merely a "view" much like `std::string_view -> std::string`. You wouldn't want the `std::string` to destruct itself if the `std::string_view` goes out of scope.

If you do want this behaviour though, creating your own wrapper around it would be trivial.

That being said, the standard [specifies](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#11):

> The coroutine state is destroyed when control flows off the end of the
> coroutine **or** the `destroy` member function
> `([coroutine.handle.resumption])` of a coroutine handle
> `([coroutine.handle])` that refers to the coroutine is invoked.

The coroutine state will clean up after itself after it has finished running and thus it won't leak unless control doesn't flow off the end.

Of course, in the generator case control typically doesn't flow off the end and thus the programmer has to destroy the coroutine manually. Coroutines have multiple uses though and the standard thus can't really unconditionally mandate the handle destructor call `destroy()`.

Comment: If I understood correctly, generator control flows typically do not end on their own as they often have infinite loops inside.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher For the generator case yes typically, but this isn't the only use for coroutines and thus you can't unconditionally call `destroy()` on a handle destructor from a standard PoV.

Comment: Pretty close to accepting this answer. The only thing that is missing is a quote from the standard stating what happens if we fail to call destroy. It's probably a leak, but it might be UB.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher AFAIK the standard doesn't say much about this. It only gives us the counter situation of calling destroy on a coroutine that's not suspended, that's UB. I believe not calling `destroy()` on it would mean you have a coroutine state that lives somewhere in memory that you can no longer access or destroy and thus results in a leak. much like not calling `delete` on `new`.

Comment: "The coroutine state is destroyed when control flows off the end of the coroutine" --> does that mean with/without a co_return, or only without?

Comment: _"This is because you want to be able to have a coroutine outlive its handle"_. In what scenario a coroutine would outlive its handle? I'm unable to think of such a scenario. Also, if such a scenario exists, then how such a coroutine will be controlled (resume/pause/etc) if the handle doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: @Nawaz Of course there should be at least 1 handle to the coroutine. My answer is supposed to convey that not *every* handle should immediately call destroy in the destructor automatically because only the last handle to live to the coroutine should call destroy on it. This is why the handle has no destroy in destructor for RAII

Comment: @HattedRooster: But the question is more like.. NONE of the handle calls `destroy()` in its destructor. `std::coroutine_handle` should be more like `std::shared_ptr` if not `std::unique_ptr`. I dont find any good reason why it didn't implement RAII, something that makes C++ so unique and powerful.

Comment: @Nawaz I don't disagree with you. It should've been a `shared_ptr` construct.