# Why does coroutine_handle's operator bool return true after destruction?

Tags: c++, c++-coroutine

I am new to C++20 coroutines and surprised to know that `coroutine_handle::operator bool` returns `true` after destruction?

Sample program:

```
#include <coroutine>
#include <iostream>

struct ReturnObject {
  struct promise_type {
    void return_void() {}
    ReturnObject get_return_object() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void unhandled_exception() {}
  };
};

struct Awaiter {
  std::coroutine_handle<> *hp_;
  constexpr bool await_ready() const noexcept { return false; }
  void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h) { *hp_ = h; }
  constexpr void await_resume() const noexcept {}
};

ReturnObject
counter(std::coroutine_handle<> *continuation_out)
{
  Awaiter a{continuation_out};
  for (;;)
    co_await a;
}

int main()
{
  std::coroutine_handle<> h;
  std::cout << "before construction " << (bool)h << '\n';
  counter(&h);
  std::cout << "after construction " << (bool)h << '\n';
  h.destroy();
  std::cout << "after destruction " << (bool)h << '\n';
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a7ehjzhab

It prints

```
before construction 0
after construction 1
after destruction 1
```

Why does it still return `true` after destruction? So it is not possible to distinguish active `coroutine_handle` from destructed one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because coroutine handle fundamentally just holds an address. You can almost think of it as a "coroutine view", it doesn't own the coroutine. [`destroy` exists if the coroutine wouldn't exit normally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68353059/332733) via standard control flow e.g. generators. `operator bool` for a `std::coroutine_handle` is defined as being equivalent to [`return (bool)address();`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle/operator_bool) unless it came from a noop promise (in which case it's just `true`).

As such when you call `.destroy()` there is no requirement (that I can find) that the handle set itself back to `nullptr` as literally doing anything with the handle after calling `destroy` (even checking `operator bool`) is as best I can tell undefined behavior.

> So it is not possible to distinguish active coroutine_handle from destructed one?

Not really? You're not intended to. Once `destroy` is called you should either get rid of the handle or reinitialize it (either with `nullptr` or a coroutine).