# Why is `await_suspend` called after `final_suspend`?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

The following code works fine, the execution returns 42:

```
0x600002aa01c0 initial_suspend
0x6000031a02a0 initial_suspend
0x6000031a02a0 await_ready
0x6000031a02a0 await_suspend (precursor = 0x600002aa01c0)
0x6000031a02a0 final_suspend
0x6000031a02a0 await_resume
0x600002aa01c0 final_suspend
Result: 42
```

However, if you comment the `co_await next_tick()` line (thus removing all `co_await` calls from the function, making it return synchronously), the output is now this:

```
0x6000008d81c0 initial_suspend
0x6000013d82a0 initial_suspend
0x6000013d82a0 final_suspend
0x6000013d82a0 await_ready
0x6000013d82a0 await_suspend (precursor = 0x6000008d81c0)
Result: 0
```

As you can see, `final_suspend` is called before `await_suspend`, causing the `precursor` variable to be empty (since it's `await_suspend` that sets it), preventing the parent coroutine from ever resuming. Is it the expected behaviour? How am I supposed to fix it?

As far as I can tell a `coroutine_handle` has no way to know whether the underlying promise still exists or not ([Why does coroutine_handle's operator bool return true after destruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68382518/why-does-coroutine-handles-operator-bool-return-true-after-destruction)), so I don't see an easy way to detect it from within `await_suspend`.

```
#include <coroutine>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

std::list<std::function<void (void)>> g_queue;

struct next_tick {
  bool await_ready() const noexcept {
    return false;
  }

  void await_resume() const noexcept {
  }

  void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> coroutine) const noexcept {
    g_queue.push_back([coroutine] {
      coroutine.resume();
    });
  }
};

// Ref https://www.jeremyong.com/cpp/2021/01/04/cpp20-coroutines-a-minimal-async-framework/
template <typename T>
struct task {
  struct promise_type {
    std::coroutine_handle<> precursor;
    T data;

    task get_return_object() noexcept {
      return {std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)};
    }

    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() noexcept {
      std::cout << std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this).address() << " initial_suspend" << std::endl;
      return {};
    }

    void unhandled_exception() {
    }

    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept {
      std::cout << std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this).address() << " final_suspend" << std::endl;

      if (precursor) {
        g_queue.push_back([this] {
          precursor.resume();
        });
      }

      return {};
    }

    void return_value(T value) noexcept {
      data = std::move(value);
    }
  };

  bool await_ready() const noexcept {
    std::cout << handle.address() << " await_ready" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }

  T await_resume() const noexcept {
    std::cout << handle.address() << " await_resume" << std::endl;
    return std::move(handle.promise().data);
  }

  void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> coroutine) const noexcept {
    std::cout << handle.address() << " await_suspend (precursor = " << coroutine.address() << ")" << std::endl;

    if (handle.done())
      coroutine.resume();

    handle.promise().precursor = coroutine;
  }

  std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle;
};

task<int> bar() {
  co_await next_tick();
  co_return 42;
}

task<int> foo() {
  co_return co_await bar();
}

int main() {
  auto coroutine = foo();

  while (!g_queue.empty()) {
    auto fn = g_queue.front();
    g_queue.pop_front();
    fn();
  }

  std::cout << "Result: " << coroutine.handle.promise().data << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Since your promise returns `suspend_never` from both `initial_suspend` and `final_suspend`, the entire coroutine runs to completion and destruction before the `task<int>` is returned. The caller then tries to `co_await` the task which has a handle to an already-destructed coroutine. You want to delay destruction of the coroutine until all `task`s that reference it have also destructed. You can do this by having `final_suspend` suspend the coroutine until all outstanding tasks have destructed.

Comment: @RaymondChen It's really surprising in some aspects, but it makes sense. I fixed it by destroying the promise from within the task destructor, but now I'll have to figure out how this all works when I need to wait for multiple promises to end. I guess I'll have to go back to your blog posts for that!